# python3 String spilt with delimiter

Tags: python-3.x

I have a long string from a text file, what I want to split

data = "|ber|undefined|Timestamp|27-8-2017 22:54:54|titel|Miss|"

here is the part where I read the file, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong to get the data printed (or in a list).

```
with open (fname, "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.readlines() 
    print (data.split('|'))
    if (check in data):
```

print (data.split('|'))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

anyone see what I'm  doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You read all the lines into data variable at once, so it contains a list. Try to split data[0] instead as follows:

```
with open (fname, "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.readlines() 
    print (data[0].split('|'))
```

Or read only one line as follows:

```
with open (fname, "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.read() 
    print (data.split('|'))
```